# Can RDS CALs without Software Assurance be migrated from an on-premise server to an Azure VM?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, azure, licensing

I'm looking into migrating our infrastructure to the cloud, replacing the use of our on-premise server running Windows Server 2008 R2 with an Azure VM running the same.

According to [this licensing FAQ](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/pricing/licensing-faq/) provided by Azure which states:

> Effective 1 January 2014, Volume Licensing customers who have active
>   Software Assurance on their RDS User CALs are entitled to RDS CAL
>   Extended Rights, which allow use of their RDS User CAL with Software
>   Assurance against a Windows Server running on Azure or other service
>   providers’ shared server environments. This RDS User CAL Software
>   Assurance benefit allows each User to access RDS functionality only on
>   one shared server environment (i.e. Azure or a third-party server) in
>   addition to access the respective on-premises servers. To obtain this
>   benefit, please complete and submit the Licence Mobility Verification
>   form to either Azure or an Authorised Mobility Partner where the
>   hosted graphical user interface will be running. More details are
>   available in Appendix 2 of the Software Assurance benefit section of
>   the PUR (Product Use Rights).

It appears you definitely need the Software Assurance to access the VM if you want to continue accessing your on-premise server, but I'm not clear if it is saying the Software Assurance is needed to access the VM, period.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure and 3rd party hosting is under what is known as SPLA Licenses (Service Provider License Agreement).  This license is rented to you, by having an active SA Agreement microsoft lets you transfer this right to them which I would assume is pre-paying the rental license fee for the term of the Software Assurance term.

No SA, No Transfer, if you install 08R2 from Azure you will be licensed for the server and unlimited users for the core OS Roles, like IIS, DC, DHCP, DNS. You then need Client Access Licenses for specific services, like RDS, Office, SQL, Dynamics, and so on.

Comment: Looking into the history of RDS on Azure a bit more, RDS was only originally available for up to two server admins to remote login and maintain the VM. When Azure originally did make RDS available it was only for Service Providers who sold RDS SALs to their customers. Now RDS is also available on Azure if you have RDS "User" CALs with SA. Is this right? Basically we would have to reinvest in this specific type of CAL (we currently have RDS "Device" CALs without SA), or become Service Providers ourselves I think.

Comment: If you haven't invested in SA, you should go the SPLA route,  and yes, 2 RDS licenses are permitted for remote administration only,  as in the standard with windows

Comment: So try signing up to become a Service Provider even if we only intend to use our SPLA SALs internally?

Comment: Can't,  you can only use up to 50% of the licenses internally

Comment: Okay, so do you know if I can buy SALs from a provider that I can use in my own Azure subscription? Our small business uses RDS to host a custom app we developed that all our locations can access remotely, so obviously the application wouldn't be offered by any other service provider who hosts Microsoft products.

Comment: that is up to the provider, Microsoft's stance is, the provider cannot load software to systems they do not own/manage & control.  BUT that can be covered in a BSA, just depends on the flexibility of the license providers.

Comment: I realize licensing topics are taboo here, so thanks for you help. I'm still trying to figure out Microsoft licensing. Namely the difference between what a Base CAL and an Additive CAL -- as described in the PDF here [link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/Licensing/learn-more/brief-base-additive-cal.aspx) -- give a user/device access to on the server. I'm confused because I don't believe we've ever purchased any other CALs except RDS Device CALs for our Win08R2 server on-prem with 18 users and everybody has access to the server desktop through RDSH.

Comment: Are the Base CALs described above what are supposed to give you access to the the Core OS roles you described in you answer? I do realize the Server License and "Base" CALs (or Core Roles) don't have to be purchased separately when using Azure since they're included in the per minute price of the VM, I'm just trying to clarify what's what.

Comment: Your best bet is to ask whomever you end up with as a license broker as it's their responsibility to provide you the right licenses, sorry I do not have a clear answer for you.